# Combined TOTP vs SMS vs Call MFA option on the B2C application

Tags: azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy, aad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c

I tested the following sample: https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/pwd-reset-via-email-or-phone

and I can see below result: [image]

However, I want to add the TOTP option to this page. I tried using the following sample but it is not giving me the expected result. Any inputs?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/multi-factor-authentication?pivots=b2c-user-flow

Answer (score 0):

> Please **note** that, you can select ***only one*** authentication method while enabling MFA.

In your scenario, you can select either **TOTP** or **SMS/call** as authentication method but not **both**.

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the below results:***

When I selected authentication method as ***SMS or phone call***, user is prompted for **MFA** like below:

[image]

To enable **`TOTP`** option, update the user flow by changing authentication method like below:

[image]

When the user ran the user flow, it prompted for **MFA** to scan `QR code` like below:

[image]

After clicking ***Continue***, they will get **`OTP`** in their **Microsoft Authenticator app** where they need to enter that code here:

[image]

Like this, you can enable **TOTP** as MFA method. But you cannot add this with **SMS or Phone call** as you can chose ***only one*** authentication method.

Answer (score 0):

keep in mind that user flows has very limited options to customize, therefore this one that you want is not available. You need a custom policy for that, more complicated, yes but there are plenty options to customize and plenty workarounds if Azure doesn't offer you what you need.

Comment: This could have been a comment. it doesn't really answer the question.